# How to find all documents that have a matching field inside an embbedded list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following collection from which I want to find only documents with a certain label:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f872944677379aa96761ae1'),
 'name': 'test',
 'labels': ['test1']}, 
{'_id': ObjectId('5f872944677379aa96761ae2'),
 'name': 'test',
 'labels': ['test1', 'test2']},
{'_id': ObjectId('5f872944677379aa96761ae3'),
 'name': 'test',
 'labels': ['test2']},
```

e.g. - I want to get all the docs with `'test2' in labels`

Tried to understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection), but since that case is using dicts and not lists as the embedded element, I can't make it work

[The following](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) mongodb example was very useful - but I need to somehow use a wildcard index, like `?` or `#`

```
db.inventory.find( { 'instock.0.qty': { $lte: 20 } } )
```

I used it like

```
col.find( { 'labels.0': 'test1' } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
db.collection.find({
  "labels": "test2"
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xYlantEf964)